# HP 15-r007tx running too slow

Tags: windows-8, laptop, performance

Just two days before I bought [HP 15-r007tx notebook](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=7089866). It came with free DOS os.
I installed windows 8.1 pro in it. From the first use after installing windows 8, it's running slow with very slow startup. I think it shouldn't happen with brand new pc even when there are no other apps being installed.

After installing applications like visual studio 2013, adobe creative suite etc.. its taking more than **3-4 minutes to boot** (from moment I press power button to the moment I can actually start any application like notepad). Also it keeps on hanging for a short moment. It takes long time to start applications like photoshop and visual studio to launch than usual. I don't know what exactly going wrong with my laptop.

I also have 6 years old desktop with intel core2Quad processor and 4gb ddr3 ram and installed same os as that I installed in new laptop. It has installed much more applications (drive C is occupying more than 100GB ) than my new laptop still it takes little more than 1 minute to boot and also works very smoothly.

Is there any tool or any way to know what is the root of the problem?? Is reinstalling the windows solve the issue??

**My laptop configuration is:**

```
Manufacturer      : HP
Model             : 15-r007tx (G8D31PA)
Processor         : Core i5 4210U (4th Generation) 
Clock Speed       : 1.7 GHz
Cache             : 3 MB
RAM               : 4 GB DDR3 1600 MHz
HDD Capacity      : 1 TB SATA 5400RPM
Graphic Processor : NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M 
Graphics Memory   : 2 GB DDR3
```

**EDIT :**

When I observed the system performance in the task manager, I noticed that the Hard disk capacity is being used by 100%. I think this is the main reason for the slow down. Can you tell me how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: [Windows 8/8.1 Painfully Slow Boot](http://www.eightforums.com/performance-maintenance/34106-windows-8-8-1-painfully-slow-boot-take-10-15-min.html) might give you some hints

Comment: Also try [Enable Verbose or Highly Detailed Status Messages In Windows 7 | 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-verbose-status-message-windows)

Comment: I would say a reinstall is a good start although its a long winded step. Have you used that Windows 8 install on any other machine, is it a legit copy as some cracked versions are full of spyware and malware and run awful off the bat...

Comment: @CharlesH: Yah! I am using the same copy on my old desktop machine and its working all the way fine.

Comment: When I observed the system performance, I noticed the disk utilization is 100%. I think this is the main reason for slowdown. How to fix this issue?

Comment: replace the HDD with a SSD like the Crucial MX100

Comment: @saurabh-palatkar: Did you find the solution to this problem? My system behaves exactly the same.

Comment: I upgraded to windows 10 + added 4GB RAM and problem solved

Comment: Fior future readers: Max disk access often coincides just after installing .net updates. Some kind of cache gets rebuild and that can take well over an hour with either max CPU or max disk (depending on which of those is the bottleneck).

Answer (score 0):

I saw your note on this problem at the hp.com support site
it's pretty obvious what the problem is with your system, the write speed is 4.1KB/sec. That's not even as fast as a 64kbps modem connection. It should be about the same as the read speed, considering that the reads & writes are both cached to a certain extent, and that's probably going to indicate the cache speed not just the disk i/o rate...you'd have to copy a file large enough to overflow the cache to get the true disk i/o rate. Anyway sounds like it's got a problem just writing to the drive.

In fact it is amazingly slow considering that you got it to boot into Windows. 
Which almost guarantees that it's a Windows problem.

Either a problem with whatever patches you have in your Windows install, or some sort of malware. But how long does it take to boot into Windows once the little circle thing shows up? Or do you have Quickboot on? You might want to go into the BIOS settings and enable UEFI & SecureBoot and turn-off Quickboot and see if that makes a difference. If it boots into Windows in a reasonable amount of time and is then slow once in Windows (especially with the disk ut. up near 100%) then it's definitely something in Windows. Is it trying to optimize your hard drive? Do you have the anti-virus running constantly, maybe it's running a disk-scan. That also should show up in the services and/or processes list. If that fails, check for notes on that particular Windows patch configuration...upgrade it to Win10.

Try configuring a Ubuntu Live CD on a USB key and boot off that and see if it runs better.